# Haxe OpenFL stablexui проект, ошибка: Widget class is not registered: meta:include

Tags: xml, flash, haxe, openfl

Я занимаюсь разработкой Flash-приложения с использованием OpenFL + stablexui для Haxe к FlashDevelop. После того, как я начал использовать тег `<meta:include>` в index.xml файле интерфейса разметки, то сразу стали появляться сообщения об ошибке  с текстом:

> Widget class is not registered: meta:include

Версия Haxe 3.2.1

Версии библиотек которые были использованы в проекте:

```
<haxelib name="openfl"   version="4.5.2"/>
<haxelib name="buddy"    version="2.6.0"/>
<haxelib name="mockatoo" version="3.2.1"/>
<haxelib name="hscript"  version="2.0.7"/>

<haxelib name="actuate"   version="1.8.7"/>
<haxelib name="stablexui" version="1.2.0"/>
<haxelib name="promhx"    version="1.1.0"/>
<haxelib name="svg"       version="1.1.1"/>
```

Часть кода главного класса инициализации:

```
import flash.Lib;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.text.Font;

import openfl.Lib;
import openfl.display.*;
import openfl.system.System;
import openfl.events.MouseEvent;

import ru.stablex.ui.*;
import ru.stablex.ui.RTXml;
import ru.stablex.ui.UIBuilder;
import ru.stablex.ui.skins.*;
import ru.stablex.ui.widgets.*;
import ru.stablex.ui.events.WidgetEvent;

import ru.mobilerockets.stablex.*;
import ru.mobilerockets.web.*;
import ru.mobilerockets.util.*;
import ru.mobilerockets.stablex.*;

class AppMain extends Sprite {
public function new() {
super();

LocalState.sharedObjectName = "state.startproject";

//----------------
//-- Init App
//----------------


UIBuilder.regClass('AppMain');
UIBuilder.init("ui/skins/defaults.xml");
UIBuilder.regSkins("ui/skins/skins.xml");

UIBuilder.buildFn("ui/index.xml")();
}
}
```

Часть XML кода index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ViewStack id="'screens'" widthPt="100" trans:Slide-direction="'left'" trans:Slide-duration="0.2">
    <meta:include src="ui/start.xml" />
    <meta:include src="ui/content.xml" />
</ViewStack>
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается проблема в библиотеке которую я подключил для функционала. stablex тут не при чем.